# Lost reputation because “user was removed”

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

I have received several downvotes from unknown users recently. What is it, and am I the only one experiencing that ?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is not downvotes.

A user that upvoted one of your answers was deleted from the system - with them, the reputation given by them has also gone.

This happens to other people too - you are not alone.

Comment: Thank you, I learned something today!